# Curl -I localhost:8888/api/config not return response

Tags: node.js

I run source nodejs. And running the command curl -I localhost: 8888/api/config returned no response. And when running in the same browser, But when running curl localhost: 8888/api/config returns the desired response. Has anyone encountered a similar error has not helped me. Search goodle did not see anyone who had such an error. Thanks all.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question or what you're trying to achieve but note that you used `-I` and it's a capital `i`  (*short for `--head`*) to fetch the **headers** only

Comment: I also resolve my issue. Thanks for your helo